# How to Parsing one childnodes in xml on android?

Tags: android, parsing, xml-parsing

I am new on android programming. I want to create applications that can be parsing an xml file. Below the xml file structure

```
<Cuaca>
<Tanggal>
<Mulai>30 March 2013</Mulai>
<MulaiPukul>07.00</MulaiPukul>
<Sampai>31 March 2013</Sampai>
<SampaiPukul>07.00</SampaiPukul>
</Tanggal>
<Isi>
<Row>
<Kota>Wates</Kota>
<point>
<coordinates>-</coordinates>
</point>
<Lintang>-7.81337</Lintang>
<Bujur>110.14757</Bujur>
<Balai>BBMKG_Ciputat</Balai>
<Propinsi>DI Yogyakarta</Propinsi>
<Cuaca>Berawan</Cuaca>
<_symbol>../imagesSWF/Berawan.swf</_symbol>
<SuhuMin>24</SuhuMin>
<SuhuMax>32</SuhuMax>
<KelembapanMin>67</KelembapanMin>
<KelembapanMax>96</KelembapanMax>
<KecepatanAngin>15</KecepatanAngin>
<ArahAngin>Tenggara</ArahAngin>
</Row>
<Row>
<Kota>Bantul</Kota>
<point>
<coordinates>-</coordinates>
</point>
<Lintang>-7.90749</Lintang>
<Bujur>110.35802</Bujur>
<Balai>BBMKG_Ciputat</Balai>
<Propinsi>DI Yogyakarta</Propinsi>
<Cuaca>Berawan</Cuaca>
<_symbol>../imagesSWF/Berawan.swf</_symbol>
<SuhuMin>24</SuhuMin>
<SuhuMax>33</SuhuMax>
<KelembapanMin>64</KelembapanMin>
<KelembapanMax>95</KelembapanMax>
<KecepatanAngin>15</KecepatanAngin>
<ArahAngin>Tenggara</ArahAngin>
</Row>
<Row>
<Kota>Wonosari</Kota>
<point>
<coordinates>-</coordinates>
</point>
<Lintang>-7.99321</Lintang>
<Bujur>110.58518</Bujur>
<Balai>BBMKG_Ciputat</Balai>
<Propinsi>DI Yogyakarta</Propinsi>
<Cuaca>Berawan</Cuaca>
<_symbol>../imagesSWF/Berawan.swf</_symbol>
<SuhuMin>25</SuhuMin>
<SuhuMax>32</SuhuMax>
<KelembapanMin>65</KelembapanMin>
<KelembapanMax>94</KelembapanMax>
<KecepatanAngin>15</KecepatanAngin>
<ArahAngin>Tenggara</ArahAngin>
</Row>
</Isi>
</Cuaca>
```

I succeed parsing the page above using DOM parser. But what I want is to just take one part from the xml file with no looping, for example:

```
<Row>
<Kota>Wates</Kota>
<point>
<coordinates>-</coordinates>
</point>
<Lintang>-7.81337</Lintang>
<Bujur>110.14757</Bujur>
<Balai>BBMKG_Ciputat</Balai>
<Propinsi>DI Yogyakarta</Propinsi>
<Cuaca>Berawan</Cuaca>
<_symbol>../imagesSWF/Berawan.swf</_symbol>
<SuhuMin>24</SuhuMin>
<SuhuMax>32</SuhuMax>
<KelembapanMin>67</KelembapanMin>
<KelembapanMax>96</KelembapanMax>
<KecepatanAngin>15</KecepatanAngin>
<ArahAngin>Tenggara</ArahAngin>
</Row>
```

anyone can help me please? Sorry if my writing is messy, it's because the first time I asked on the forums.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse particular node then you need to move to that node like this,

```
   NodeList row_nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("Row");
                   for (int i = row_id; i < row_nodes.getLength();) {
                           org.w3c.dom.Element row_element = (org.w3c.dom.Element) row_nodes                                            .item(i);


                           break;
                   }
```

Here `row_id` is number of particular node 
like, if `row_id` is 0 then it will parse

```
<Row>
<Kota>Wates</Kota>
...
</Row>
```

if `row_id` is 1 then it will parse

```
<Row>
<Kota>Bantul</Kota>
...
</Row>
```

if `row_id` is 2 then it will parse

```
<Row>
<Kota>Wonosari</Kota>
...
</Row>
```

Hope this helps you,

Comment: I just try what you tell me, but when I run the emulator just show white screen. Can you tell me where I'am got wrong?
Here's my code

    NodeList row_nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ROW);
    ...
    break;

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    pDialog.dismiss();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    ListAdapter adapter = SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this,menuItems, R.layout.list_kota, new String[] {KEY_KOTA, ... }, new int[] { R.id.kota, ... });
    setListAdapter(adapter);